# Extracting data from a struct within a .mat file

Tags: matlab

Below I have provided a boiled down version of my code that illustrates the point. I am loading a file into Matlab that I have. It loads fine, but this is about accessing data within the `data` struct of the `.mat` file.

```
load('final_data_file.mat')
pres = data.getElement('p_star');
Vas = data.getElement('Vabc_true(1)')
```

Spits out:
`Warning: Did not find any Dataset element using 'Vabc_true(1)'.`

The `pres` works just fine; it is the `Vas` is where I am having the issue. I have also tried `Vas = data.Vabc_true.getElement('Vabc_true')` to no avail. You see, Vas is data that is stored in a separate struct within the file. How do I access the separate struct?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer.

What I needed to do was the following:

```
Vas = data.getElement('Vabc_true');
Va = Vas.Data;
```